# How does solr loads configsets in examples provided by solr?

Tags: solr, lucene

I have started learning solr.I have downloaded the latest zip(5.1.0) provided by solr and run the server using  bin/solr start -e cloud -noprompt.
I check that this internally calls

```
 bin/solr start -cloud -s example/cloud/node1/solr -p 8983 
 bin/solr start -cloud -s example/cloud/node2/solr -p 7574 -z localhost:9983
```

I check that these is no config(conf/solrconfig.xml)  defined in example/cloud/node1/solr   so how does solr load config from the SOLR_HOME/configsets directory?

I read the documentation on several places but i am still unable to figure out the use of cloud like in 'bin/solr start -cloud -s ... '  and use of zookeeper.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

when you are working on solr cloud with zookeeper, you have to upload your solr config on zookeeper.

./bin/solr zk -upconfig -z localhost:2181,localhost:2182,localhost:2182 -n my-config -d server/solr/files/conf/

using upconfig you can upload your solr config, only have to provide path of your config directory.

You can use config name(my-config) for create core using api.

http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=irTest&numShards=3&replicationFactor=2&maxShardsPerNode=3&collection.configName=my-config

So it will create core using your config only.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version of the Apache solr reference guide. 
https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/lucene/solr/ref-guide/apache-solr-ref-guide-5.1.pdf

check this section in the PDF. 
**Configuration Directories and SolrCloud**

Since you are not specifying a specific configset, the default is loaded.

> First, if you don't provide the -d or -n options, then the default
>   configuration ($SOLR_HOME/server/solr/con
>   figsets/data_driven_schema_configs/conf) is uploaded to ZooKeeper
>   using the same name as the collection

Comment: Is zookeeper mandatory to run a solr instance? What exactly it does?Can't i run my own core or examples provided by solr without zookeeper?

Comment: Zookeeper is needed if you are using Solr in cloud mode. Zookeeper takes care of storing the configurations and also coordinating the nodes in SolrCloud. You do not have to use ZK. You can create your own set of individual solr nodes, and use the distributed search to query among them. Of course in that case, you will need to decide from application side about which data you should index in which node. You can find more details on this link : https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch